# Is Link2SD completely safe on a rooted device?

Tags: root-access, sd-card, app2sd, link2sd

I have a rooted device, and I was wondering:

Is Link2SD app safe to allow root access to? Is it a scam or anything?

Does it work as is says it does and does it actually save the stuff to the SD card?

And can it break or damage my device or apps in any way?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Nobody can give you guarantees, but Link2SD has a good reputation. Check out our [link2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info) and [questions using that tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link2sd) to read more.

Comment: Like what @Izzy said, can't guarantee anything, but with 10m downloads and 1/4 m reviews with an avg rating for 4.3 in the playstore. I am pretty sure its safe. **Edit:** As far as, how does it work and whatnot. Take a look at their faq. http://www.link2sd.info/faq or the Wiki link Izzy provided.

Comment: Noting related  to root is completely  safe (tampering may brick your device) ,  but, like the fine men above me said ,  it is deemed reliable and safe

Comment: That safe part you asked would only invite opinions here since when it comes to testing the code only the source code investigation would lead you to final answer. If you've the complete code, start investigating it, or look for somebody who already did that.

Comment: But does it actually move the apps to the SD card like it says? And if I install an OTA update will my apps still work as I will lose root?